# Hive issue with strings

Tags: sql, apache, hive

I am trying to deal with a substring issue in Hive.

I have a column value and I am using SUBSTR to try and see if the value is what i need.

...

WHERE SUBSTR(A.item1, 1, 5)='FOLDE'
...

I am trying to see if the first 5 letter of item1 is 'FOLDE' but I am getting this error from HIVE:

FAILED: ParseException line 4:40 character '‘' not supported here
line 4:46 character '’' not supported here

Comment: The SQL-ish way to compare a string value to a string literal would be `where a.ITEM1 like 'FOLDE%'`

Comment: And since you do not explain what version of Hive you are using, with what kind of SerDe (Text, RCFile, AVRO, Parquet, ORC) and what exact query you are running, I strongly doubt anyone can help you debug this.

Comment: my apologies. I am using Hive 1.0.0. Here is the query: SELECT n_id, count(*) AS event_count
FROM all_events
WHERE SUBSTR(all_events.event_id,1,5)='FOLDE’
GROUP BY all_events.n_id
ORDER BY event_count DESC
LIMIT 5;               The problem is that I am not able to use any type of quotes to signify the match for 'FOLDE'. It says " ' " not supported and same error for double quotes.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using plain ASCII quotes, and not typographic quotes `such as ‘these’` -- the kind that bloody in Microsoft Word creates automatically?

Comment: yup, im physically typing the quotes and it just keeps saying "not support here"

Comment: Same thing with `where EVENT_ID like 'FOLDE%'` ??